# What's the difference between p =var and p #{var} in Jade?

Tags: pug

As per title, I can't understand when I need to use `p= var` or `p #{var}` in Jade. What's the difference between them and when should I use the first instead of the second?

Comment: Did you mean `#{var}`?

Comment: @devnull yes, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let say you want to display some text with variables then you would use `p #{var}`

```
i = 10
p The value of i is #{i}
```

The above code would become the following

`<p>The value of i is 10</p>`

In the case of `p= var` jade parse the entire text after the '=' sign as javascript so in order to obtain the above result you would have to write

```
i = 10
p= 'The value of i is' + i
```

Check out the demo [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/yfrjxpub)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about template data?

Comment: Didn't understand your query? I have added a live demo link

Comment: The example is fine, my question is about raw template data (not variables defined inside templates). With template data (i.e. `template({ title: 'foo' })`, should I use `p= title` or `p #{title}`?

Comment: Again it depends on your preference both will work. I would use `p= title` as there is no static text to be added but if it had static text then I would use the latter like this `p Hello #{title}`